# Why isn't my audio file playing in Firefox?

Tags: ajax, firefox, audio

I am calling an Ajax function called AjaxSound() to play an audio file under certain event conditions on my site. I am changing the innerHTML of a div in home.php by echoing the audio file in my Ajax call as follows in AJAX_Sound.php:

```
echo "<embed src=\"AudioFiles/Sound.mp3\" volume=\"100\"    
loop=\"false\" type=\"audio/mpeg\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
```

This worked perfectly in IE and Chrome, which means my AjaxSound() is written properly and AJAX_Sound.php is also written properly for these browsers. However, no audio file was played in FF (version 24.0) nor Opera. So I used advice shown here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) to create the following alternative echo statements using .wav and .ogg files:

```
echo "<embed src=\"AudioFiles/Sound.wav\" volume=\"100\" 
loop=\"false\" type=\"audio/wave\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";


echo "<embed src=\"AudioFiles/Sound.ogg\" volume=\"100\"    
loop=\"false\" type=\"audio/ogg\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
```

However, the audio files are still not playing in FF and Opera. I have alternatively tried type=\"audio/x-wav\" as suggested on the Mozilla forum. Any idea about what I can add (or take away) from my echo statements? I know this is more of a browser configuration issue but as I am new to audio files on my website, I wonder if I have completely omitted something important from my echo statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...solved it by calling a javascript play() function with each ajax iteration....now plays in Firefox. Still didn't work on Opera though but not too worried about this right now!